# Fiddler doesn't capture traffic from remote clients on virtual machine

Tags: vmware, http, fiddler

I have Fiddler installed on a virtual machine (VMware). I want to monitor incoming HTTP traffic (requests from remote clients). But Fiddler doesn't show any incoming HTTP requests. Outcoming requests are shown properly. All requests are processed properly (it means that HTTP requests are received but aren't shown in Fiddler)

I've found a bunch of questions regarding this problem and tried all things that were mentioned (checked rules, ensured that monitoring is enabled for all processes, checkbox 'allow connections from remote clients is checked, and so on). I even tried to reinstall Fiddler but it didn't help either.

I think it might be because of virtual machine - but I have no idea why it is happening and how to solve it. Wireshark shows all traffic but I need Fiddler to use it as a reverse proxy (some requests modification might be required).

Could someone explain what may cause this and how to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you configured the remote machines to connect to the host running Fiddler as a proxy?

Comment: @RowlandShaw How to do it? I connect to a server (virtual machine) as usual, using IP and port.

Comment: @RowlandShaw Fiddler is configured to listen specific port, 777 and  clients connect to this port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, it was because of firewall - the port I tried to connect to was simply closed.
Also make sure that clients connect to a port that Fiddler listens as described here http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy